How to debug Shiny app plot that won't render
I am trying to build a shiny app for a class that allows you to customize a simple heatmap plot.  I was able to get the plot output I want in R outside of Shiny, but am running into issues with the app implementation.  The data that I am using is

structure(list(Distance = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,  100L,
100L, 100L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L,  150L,
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 250L,  250L,
250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 300L, 300L, 300L,  300L,
300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L,  350L,
350L, 350L, 350L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L,  400L,
400L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L ),
Direction = c("Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left",  "Left",
"Right", "Right", "Right", "Center", "Center", "Center",  "Left",
"Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Center",  "Center",
"Center", "Left", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right",  "Right",
"Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left", "Left",  "Right",
"Right", "Right", "Center", "Center", "Center", "Left",  "Left",
"Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Center", "Center",  "Center",
"Left", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right",  "Center",
"Center", "Center", "Left", "Left", "Left", "Right",  "Right",
"Right", "Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left",  "Left",
"Right", "Right", "Right"), Offset = c(0, 0, 0, 20, 20,  20, 20, 20,
20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20,  20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0,  20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0,
0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0,  0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0,
0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5,
7.5), Height = c(12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L,  12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L,  24L, 36L,
12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L,  36L, 12L, 24L,
36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L,  12L, 24L, 36L, 12L,
24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L,  24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L,
12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L), Horizontal = c(0.1,
0.15, 0.1, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.13, 0.11, 0.06, 0.05, 0.06, 0.02,
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01,
0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.05,
0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02,
0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02,
0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02,
0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02), Vertical = c(2.3, 1.43, 0.7, 0.49,
0.12, 0.07, 0.88, 0.74, 0.6, 0.47, 0.34, 0.23, 0.04, 0.04, 0.03,
0.5, 0.43, 0.32, 0.3, 0.23, 0.17, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.3, 0.25,
0.19, 0.3, 0.23, 0.17, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2, 0.17,
0.13, 0.1, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2, 0.18, 0.15, 0.14, 0.12, 0.09,
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.08, 0.07, 0.02, 0.02,
0.01, 0.11, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.08, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.04, 0.12,
0.1, 0.07)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -72L))

And the complete code for my app is
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
jsCode <- "
shinyjs.colorInputBinding = function() {
  $('#colorLowInput').on('change', function() {
    Shiny.setInputValue('colorLow', $('#colorLowInput').val());
  });
  $('#colorHighInput').on('change', function() {
    Shiny.setInputValue('colorHigh', $('#colorHighInput').val());
  });
}"

#read in the data
light_data <- read.csv("lightData.csv",
                       header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Dynamic Heatmap and Data Display"),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("colorInputBinding")),
  
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$label("Lower Color"),
      tags$input(type = "color", id = "colorLowInput", value = "#0000FF"),
      tags$br(),
      tags$label("Higher Color"),
      tags$input(type = "color", id = "colorHighInput", value = "#FF0000"),
      sliderInput("heightFilter", "Select Height", min = 12, max = 36, value = c(12, 36)),
      radioButtons("dataView", "Select Data View", choices = list("All Data" = "all", "Filtered Data" = "filtered"))
    ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(id = "MainPanel", selected = "Plot Output",
                    tabPanel(Title = "Plot Output", value="Plot",  plotOutput(outputId = "heatmap")),
                    tabPanel(Title = "Data Table", value="Table", DTOutput(outputId = "dataTable"))
        )
      )
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    data <- light_data %>%
      filter(Height >= input$heightFilter[1] & Height <= input$heightFilter[2])
    if (input$dataView == "filtered") {
      return(data)
    } else {
      return(light_data)
    }
  })
  
  output$heatmap <- renderPlot({
    req(input$colorLow, input$colorHigh)
    data <- filtered_data()
    #print(head(data))
    #if (nrow(data) == 0) {
    #  return()
    #}
    
    ggplot(data, aes(x = Distance, y = factor(Height), fill = Horizontal)) +
      geom_tile() +
      scale_fill_gradient(low = input$colorLow, high = input$colorHigh) +
      labs(title = "Heatmap of Horizontal Light Intensity",
           x = "Distance from Truck (ft)",
           y = "Height (in)",
           fill = "Intensity (Fc)") +
      theme_minimal()
  }, height = "auto",
  width = "auto")
  
  output$dataTable <- renderDT({
    datatable(filtered_data(), options = list(pageLength = 5))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

When I run the app, I don't really see the tabs I expect, and there is an error message that says error: figure margins too large.  I thought that having height = "auto", width = "auto" in the renderPlot() would have taken care of that?
It's entirely possible I'm screwing something up with the reactive data filtering, but I'm not sure how to debug this from this point.

One of the best approaches to debugging is to start from scratch and test pieces as you add them back.
For example, I started with your filtered_data reactive and made sure it was outputting the data as desired. One thing I did was cat(length(filtered_data()[[1]])) as the first line in your renderPlot() to observe if the filtering was removing rows. I then turned my attention to your plot where I commented out all the lines and added them back one-by-one until I found an issue with the scale_fill_gradient() line. This led me to realize there were issues with your color picker implementation. Instead of debugging that, I am suggesting to use a pre-rolled color picker from the {colourpicker} package.
Here is your code with these changes:

Switched to using colourpicker::colourInput() to avoid the complexity of rolling your own color input.
Edited Title to title in both tabPanel()s
For the selected argument of tabsetPanel() use the tabPanel() value argument as opposed to the title argument

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(colourpicker)

light_data <- structure(list(Distance = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 350L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L ), Direction = c("Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Center", "Center", "Center", "Left", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right"), Offset = c(0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5), Height = c(12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 36L), Horizontal = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.13, 0.11, 0.06, 0.05, 0.06, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.05, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02), Vertical = c(2.3, 1.43, 0.7, 0.49, 0.12, 0.07, 0.88, 0.74, 0.6, 0.47, 0.34, 0.23, 0.04, 0.04, 0.03, 0.5, 0.43, 0.32, 0.3, 0.23, 0.17, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.3, 0.25, 0.19, 0.3, 0.23, 0.17, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2, 0.17, 0.13, 0.1, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2, 0.18, 0.15, 0.14, 0.12, 0.09, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.08, 0.07, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.11, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.08, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.04, 0.12, 0.1, 0.07)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -72L))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Heatmap and Data Display"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      colourInput("colorLowInput", "Lower Color", value = "#0000FF"),
      tags$br(),
      colourInput("colorHighInput", "Higher Color", value = "#FF0000"),
      sliderInput(
        "heightFilter",
        "Select Height",
        min = 12,
        max = 36,
        value = c(12, 36)
      ),
      radioButtons(
        "dataView",
        "Select Data View",
        choices = list("All Data" = "all", "Filtered Data" = "filtered")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "MainPanel",
        selected = "Plot",
        tabPanel(
          title = "Plot Output",
          value = "Plot",
          plotOutput(outputId = "heatmap")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          title = "Data Table",
          value = "Table",
          DTOutput(outputId = "dataTable")
        )
      )
    )
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    data <- light_data %>%
      filter(Height >= input$heightFilter[1] &
               Height <= input$heightFilter[2])
    if (input$dataView == "filtered") {
      return(data)
    } else {
      return(light_data)
    }
  })
  
  output$heatmap <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(
      x = Distance,
      y = factor(Height),
      fill = Horizontal
    )) +
      geom_tile() +
      scale_fill_gradient(low = input$colorLowInput,
                          high = input$colorHighInput) +
      labs(
        title = "Heatmap of Horizontal Light Intensity",
        x = "Distance from Truck (ft)",
        y = "Height (in)",
        fill = "Intensity (Fc)"
      ) +
      theme_minimal()
  })
  
  output$dataTable <- renderDT({
    datatable(filtered_data(), options = list(pageLength = 5))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7769


Created on 2024-04-22 with reprex v2.1.0

The problem with the height is that if you specify width = "auto" and height = "auto" in renderPlot, this yields (from ?renderPlot)

"auto", the default, uses the size specified by plotOutput() (i.e. the
offsetWidth/'offsetHeight“ of the HTML element bound to this plot.)

And these ones (width = "100%", height = "400px", from ?plotOutput) are not suitable for the implementation inside your tabsetPanel, hence you should explicitly set suitable values inside renderPlot.
Additionally, notice that you need to call js$colorInputBinding() inside the server since otherwise your js does not get invoked.
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

jsCode <- "
shinyjs.colorInputBinding = function() {
  $('#colorLowInput').on('change', function() {
    Shiny.setInputValue('colorLow', $('#colorLowInput').val());
  });
  $('#colorHighInput').on('change', function() {
    Shiny.setInputValue('colorHigh', $('#colorHighInput').val());
  });
}"

#read in the data
light_data <- read.csv("lightData.csv",
                       header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Dynamic Heatmap and Data Display"),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("colorInputBinding")),
  
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$label("Lower Color"),
      tags$input(
        type = "color",
        id = "colorLowInput",
        value = "#0000FF"
      ),
      tags$br(),
      tags$label("Higher Color"),
      tags$input(
        type = "color",
        id = "colorHighInput",
        value = "#FF0000"
      ),
      sliderInput(
        "heightFilter",
        "Select Height",
        min = 12,
        max = 36,
        value = c(12, 36)
      ),
      radioButtons(
        "dataView",
        "Select Data View",
        choices = list("All Data" = "all", "Filtered Data" = "filtered")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "MainPanel",
        selected = "Plot Output",
        tabPanel(
          Title = "Plot Output",
          value = "Plot",
          plotOutput(outputId = "heatmap")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          Title = "Data Table",
          value = "Table",
          DTOutput(outputId = "dataTable")
        )
      )
    )
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    data <- light_data %>%
      filter(Height >= input$heightFilter[1] &
               Height <= input$heightFilter[2])
    if (input$dataView == "filtered") {
      return(data)
    } else {
      return(light_data)
    }
  })
  
  output$heatmap <- renderPlot({
    data <- filtered_data()
    
    ggplot(data, aes(
      x = Distance,
      y = factor(Height),
      fill = Horizontal
    )) +
      geom_tile() +
      scale_fill_gradient(
        low = ifelse(!is.null(input$colorLow),
                     input$colorLow,
                     "#0000FF"),
        high = ifelse(!is.null(input$colorHigh),
                      input$colorHigh,
                      "#FF0000")
      ) +
      labs(
        title = "Heatmap of Horizontal Light Intensity",
        x = "Distance from Truck (ft)",
        y = "Height (in)",
        fill = "Intensity (Fc)"
      ) +
      theme_minimal()
  }, height = 400,
  width = 400)
  
  output$dataTable <- renderDT({
    datatable(filtered_data(), options = list(pageLength = 5))
  })
  
  js$colorInputBinding()
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

